# Disable X's middle-mouse paste functionality in a window manager

Tags: window-managers, xcb

I'm writing a window manager with xcb and I'm wondering if there's anything I can do about the default functionality of pasting on middle-mouse clicking. It's very difficult (seemingly impossible) to get rid of it from an end-user perspective, but could there be a way to do this when I'm handling button press events myself?